# How to handle multiple API Requests

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-admin-sdk

I am working with the [Google Admin SDK to create Google Groups for my organization](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#create_group). I can't add members to the group when creating the group, ideally, when I create a new group I'd like to add roughly 60 members. In addition, the ability to add members after the group is created in bulk (a batch request) [was deprecated August 2020](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch). Right now, after I create a group I need to make a web request to the API to add each member of the group individually (which will be about 60 members).

I am using node.js and express, is there a good way to handle 60 web requests to an api? I don't know how taxing this will be on my server. If anyone has any resources to share where I can learn about the impact this would have on a nodejs server that would be great.

Fortunately, these groups aren't created often, maybe 15 a month.

One idea I have is to offload the work to something like a cloud function so my node server makes one request to the cloud function, then the cloud function makes all the additional requests to add members to the Group. I'm not 100% sure if this is necessary and I'm curious on other approaches.

Comment: you can use `clusters` to run multiple instances of your application which will handle the load efficiently.

Comment: Is that a technical problem or are you expressing an opinion that this is inconvenient? Timeouts are measured in seconds/minutes for an app in App Engine, Cloud Functions, etc. How long does 60 API calls take in your environment? Post your code, the results and errors, and the problem that you need solved.

Comment: I'm not stating an opinion, I've generally worked with single api requests. I am trying to decide if it is acceptable to essentially loop through a list of api calls and make 60 calls synchronously (or fire them all asynchronously). I don't know much about the stress this would cause to server and am hoping to find out if this is a common acceptable practice OR if this is a bad practice and I should look into offloading the requests, scheduling them, etc.

Comment: 60 is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

### [Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits)

*Note that adding group members may take 10 minutes to propagate.*

The rate limit for the Directory API is 3000 queries per 100 seconds per IP address. This works out to around 30 per second. 60 requests is not a large amount of requests, but if you try to send them all in a few milliseconds the system *may* extrapolate the rate and deem it over the limit, I wouldn't think so, though probably best to test it on your end with your system and connection etc.

### [Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits#backoff)

If you do need to make many requests this is the method Google recommends. It involves repeating the request if it fails and then exponentially increasing the amount of time to wait until it reaches 16 seconds. You can always implement a longer wait to retry. Its only 60 requests after all.

### [Batch Requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch)

The previously mentioned methods should work no issue for you, since there are only 60 requests to make, it won't put any "stress" on the system as such. That said, the most performant way to handle many requests to the Directory API is to use a batch request. This allows you to bundle up all your member requests into one large batch, of up to 1000 calls. This will also give you a nice cushion in case you need to increase your requests in future!

**EDIT** - I am sorry, I missed that you mentioned that Batching is deprecated. Only **global** batching is deprecated. If you send a batch request to a specific API, batching will still be supported. What you can no longer do is send a single batch request to different APIs, like Directory *and* Sheets in one.

#### References

- [Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits)
- [Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits#backoff)
- [Batch Requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch)